# Nutch 1.x: How to use s3a instead of HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, hdfs, nutch

I have read the official [Apache Nutch with Hadoop tutorial](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/nutch/NutchHadoopTutorial). It talks about using HDFS to store Nutch's data when using Nutch in "deploy mode" (i.e. within a Hadoop cluster).

When using Hadoop, I prefer using s3a over HDFS as storage backend. Does Nutch 1.x support using s3a instead of HDFS for storing data? If so, which are the relevant Nutch/Hadoop settings to tweak?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recent versions of Nutch 1.x (1.14 and above, see [NUTCH-2281](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH-2281)) support the s3a filesystem out of the box if the underlying Hadoop supports it.

Note: Usually, s3a is slower than HDFS, see [S3A performance issues](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html#Other_issues). This applies especially to Nutch's CrawlDb or LinkDb. The CrawlDb is updated every cycle and this is done first by writing the new CrawlDb to a new directory and then replacing the active CrawlDb (called "current") by moving the new one to "current". The "mv" is cheap on HDFS but isn't on S3A.

Eventually, you may want to keep the CrawlDb on HDFS and checkpoint it on S3A using "distcp".

Comment: Thank you. Is `file://` (the local filesystem) supported too?

Comment: The local file system is used for storage in local mode. In fully distributed mode it can be hardly used because any file put on `file://` must be visible and reachable on all cluster nodes. For crawling the local file system there is a plugin "protocol-file".